# Ruby Thor options with white space

Tags: ruby, whitespace, thor

for an assignment I am doing I am required to have an option "--format oneline" where my output is formatted in one line.

I have successfully done this, but only if I use --formatoneline (without the white space). If I include the white space it seperates the option into 2 arguments ["format", "oneline"].

I'd like to know how to deal with the white space character here, as the assignment requires very specific formatting.

This is coded using ruby and the Thor Module.

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `:type` for an option. Take a look [here.](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki/Method-Options)

```
method_option :format, type: :string
```

And then you can check if there is `--format oneline`

```
if options[:format] == 'oneline'
   # puts smth
end
```

Comment: Any chance you could help me understand how I would do the same procedure but with "no-country-code"? It seems like the hyphens aren't appreciated.

Comment: You can do it like that: `method_option :'country-code'`. With `no` you could call it like that: `--no-country-code`. Hope it's what you are looking for.